# Professors and theologians?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm somewhat bemused by the "About" page of the main site, which says:

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for professors, theologians, and those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts.

Is this a case of trying to find three categories of target audience for rhetorical effect as a higher priority than making sense? Or is the subtext that once a university appoints you to a chair you cease to be a theologian? (The other possibility which occurs to me is that it's intended to invite in professors of engineering, but that makes even less sense).

Why not just

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for theologians and those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts.

?

Comment: "professor" [means something different depending on where you are from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor) - another good reason to remove it from the FAQ, thanks Peter

Comment: To me, professors can include or exclude theologians.  A Biology professor would obviously have no interest in this site.  I went ahead and removed it since it was a bit too broad.  Normally these things are decided by the community, but as a temporary measure, I've dropped the strange word.

Answer (score 3):

That first paragraph we have full control to edit.  We can add whatever we want to that paragraph.  [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) is my favorite example of this.

Realistically, we need to change this first section to say what we want it to say.  This will need to be a separate meta post about this, though.

In the meantime, I went ahead and dropped professors (for no other reason than it makes sense).  Once we agree on a permanent text, this will all probably be gone.